# Limit the throughput of a Reactor Flux reading a Mongodb collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, project-reactor, reactive-kafka

I am using Spring 5, in detail the Reactor project, to read information from a huge Mongo collection to a Kafka topic. Unfortunately, the production of Kafka messages is much faster than the program that consumes them. So, I need to implement some *backpressure* mechanism.

Suppose I want a throughput of 100 messages every second. Googling a little, I decided to combine the feature of the [`buffer(int maxSize)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer-int-) method, [zipping](http://javasampleapproach.com/reactive-programming/reactor/reactor-create-flux-interval-reactive-programming) the result with a `Flux` that emits a message using a predefined interval.

```
 // Create a clock that emits an event every second
 final Flux<Long> clock = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000L));
 // Create a buffered producer
 final Flux<ProducerRecord<String, Data>> outbound =
            repository.findAll()
                      .map(this::buildData)
                      .map(this::createKafkaMessage)
                      .buffer(100)
                      // Limiting the emission in time interval
                      .zipWith(clock, (msgs, tick) -> msgs)
                      .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable);
 // Subscribe a Kafka sender
 kafkaSender.createOutbound()
            .send(outbound)
            .then()
            .block();
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? I mean, it seems to me a little bit complex (the zip part, overall).

Comment: Would rather use akka stream with provide back pressure support

Comment: @cchantep, thanks for the hint. However, the question was not about which is the best reactive-stream implementation, but how to solve the problem using Reactor.

Comment: Indeed, but either Kafka ans mongo have akka stream modules, composable together, thus this situation would not be an issue

Comment: Ok, next project I will give a chance also to Akka Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` operation directily whitout need to zipWith it. There is always enhancement with reactor cool project as it a continious upgrades so let us be sticky :) hope was helpful!

Comment: Well, nice solution. However, I using `delayElements` methods makes the whole execution longer than using the `zipWith` technique. Can you guess why?

Comment: Little bit strange. I wonder if it is suitable to you to use Durations.ofMillis(500) instead of Durations.ofSecond(1) ?

Comment: I was using `Durations.ofMillis(1000L)`.

Comment: It seems that the method `delayElements` consumes much less CPU time than the `zip` with a tick process :)